# Minimizing rows with a merge/squish in Pandas DataFrame with Multiple indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With a DataFrame like,

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id_1': [33,33,33,33,22,22,88,100],
    'id_2': [64,64,64,64,12,12,77,100],
    'col_1': [np.nan, 'dog', np.nan, 'kangaroo', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'col_2': ['bike', 'car', np.nan, np.nan, 'train', np.nan, 'horse', np.nan],
    'col_3': [np.nan, np.nan, 'star', 'meteor', np.nan, 'rock', np.nan, np.nan]
})

"""
   id_1  id_2     col_1  col_2   col_3
0    33    64       NaN   bike     NaN
1    33    64       dog    car     NaN
2    33    64       NaN    NaN    star
3    33    64  kangaroo    NaN  meteor
4    22    12       NaN  train     NaN
5    22    12       NaN    NaN    rock
6    88    77       NaN  horse     NaN
7   100   100       NaN    NaN     NaN
"""
```

How can it be transformed into a minimum amount of rows without aggregating or losing data like the following?

```
   id_1  id_2     col_1  col_2   col_3
0    33    64       dog   bike    star
1    33    64  kangaroo    car  meteor
3    22    12       NaN  train    rock
4    88    77       NaN  horse     NaN
5   100   100       NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Basically, for each group of `id_X` columns, the `col_X` columns' `NaN` values are replaced with other group values if applicable.

Comment: How do you deal with ids (33, 64) where you have values dog, bike, star, kangaroo, car, and meteor and space for only 3 values?

Comment: @ifly6 those IDs should stay the same, and their duplicates dropped. The 4 rows of (33, 64) becomes two rows of (33, 64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid illegible Pandas voodoo, after your imports and df instantiation, you can do

```py
def get_max_vals_from_row_sets(row, cols):
  mn = 1
  for col in cols:
    mn = max(mn, len(row[col]))
  return mn

def add_id_row(d, row, ids, cols):
  max_vals = get_max_vals_from_row_sets(row, cols)

  for _ in range(max_vals):
    for id_ in ids:
      d[id_].append(row[id_])

    for col in cols:
      if len(row[col]) != 0:
        d[col].append(row[col].pop())
      else:
        d[col].append(np.nan)

def drop_set_nans(row, cols):
  for col in cols:
    if np.nan in row[col]:
      row[col].remove(np.nan)
  return row

def squash_out_redundant_nans(df, ids, cols):
  df = df.groupby(ids).agg(set).reset_index()
  d = {k: [] for k in df.columns}
  for _, row in df1.iterrows():
    drop_set_nans(row, cols)
    add_id_row(d, row, ids, cols)

  df = pd.DataFrame(d)
  return df

ids = ['id_1', 'id_2']
cols = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']
df = squash_out_redundant_nans(df, ids, cols)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# melt (wide to long) on id_1, id_2 and sort the values
# this brings the NaN to the top

df2=df.melt(id_vars=['id_1', 'id_2'], var_name='col').sort_values(['id_1', 'id_2','col', 'value'])

# create a seq, to make the keys unique and pivot
df3=(df2.assign(seq=df2.groupby(['id_1','id_2','col' ]).cumcount())
 .pivot(index=['id_1','id_2','seq'], columns=['col'], values='value').reset_index()
)

# for id_1 =100, you have all NaN and still want to keep it
# so remove rows with all NaN except when its for seq=0
df3=df3.loc[~((df3['seq']>0) & 
          (df3[['col_1','col_2','col_3']].isna().all(axis=1)) )]

# drop the seq (temp) column
df3.drop(columns='seq', inplace=True)
df3
```

```
col     id_1    id_2    col_1   col_2   col_3
0   22  12  NaN     train   rock
2   33  64  dog     bike    meteor
3   33  64  kangaroo    car     star
6   88  77  NaN     horse   NaN
7   100     100     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
# this is to push up all not NaN values to the top of each column
df.loc[:, 'col_1':'col_3'] = df.groupby(
    ['id_1', 'id_2'], sort=False).transform(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull))

# this is to remove all useless rows of NaN
df.loc[~(df.duplicated(['id_1', 'id_2']) &
         df.loc[:, 'col_1':'col_3'].isna().all(axis=1))]
```

Output:

```
   id_1  id_2     col_1  col_2   col_3
0    33    64       dog   bike    star
1    33    64  kangaroo    car  meteor
4    22    12       NaN  train    rock
6    88    77       NaN  horse     NaN
7   100   100       NaN    NaN     NaN
```